# Add session support to express after setup

Tags: node.js, session, express

I am just starting to figure out nodejs and I forgot to put in the flag for session support

```
$ express -s somefolder
```

Can I run the above command without overwriting anything I already added or changed or do I have to do something else?

it is not as clear as adding a new dependancy (stylus) to package.json and rerun `$ npm install`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update**:

Session support is now added via the [expressjs/session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) module.

To install:

```
npm install -save express-session
```

To use:

```
import * as session from "express-session";
...
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({ secret: "..." });
```

Be sure to visit the module on GitHub to get the latest installation and usage instructions.

**Original answer**:

Just add the session middleware to your Express app.js file.

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({secret: '1234567890QWERTY'}));
```

Make sure it comes after the `express.cookieParser()` call.  Also, update the `secret` value to a random string for security.

Comment: really is this all? just checked the Express documentation again and could not find it, thanks